# Seamless Handover in Windows CE 5.0 and higher using WLAN and VPN over GPRS

Tags: networking, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I have a little tricky problem using network under windows ce with .net compact framework.

I will try to describe...

First of all there are three types of connections established while starting my application.

First one is a WLAN Connection to company network

second one is a gprs connection

third one is a OpenVPN connection that should use gprs underlying.

Default way is that the user is in WLAN area and connects to company network.
But some times the user has to leave WLAN area but needs network connection, so the connection should seamless switch to GRPS over OpenVPN.
If the user enters the WLAN area again, connection should seamless switch to WLAN.

So I have tried to observe the connections to get notified if wifi goes down and then to switch to gprs.

Now my problem is that I can't find a way to decide wich network adapter is used if I open a socket TCP-Connection in my application.

Is there any way?

Update:

Now I've tried something like this:

```
 foreach (NetworkInterface inf in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                if (inf.Name == "Cellular Line")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        IPAddress addr = inf.CurrentIpAddress;
                        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(addr, 10);
                        sock.Bind(ep);
                        IPEndPoint remoteTcpServer = new IPEndPoint(3025045080, 8000);
                        sock.Connect(remoteTcpServer);
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

If there is only one adapter is powered on it will work. But if I enable WLAN and GPRS the connection fails...

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Is your requirement Windows CE or Windows Mobile?  The answer is different depending on the platform.  Windows CE is not exactly the same thing as Windows Mobile.  Are you using RAS or ConnMgr to establish the network connections?

Comment: There is no special device the software is running on. Our customers can have any device they want. It is limitted by windows ce 5.0 and can be every newer version so it can also be a windows mobile 5.0 or higher or a windows ce 6.0 device. Actually I don't manage the connection. It will be a feature in next version that the software supports seamless handover.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows Mobile there is a much simpler way to go about using the optimal connection: use Connection Manager.  It will connect via Wi-Fi as first priority if available.  Connection Manager should choose in this order: Wi-Fi -> VPN -> GPRS based on availability of those connections.  You can even specify the adapter to use if you want full control over the connection choice.  Connection Manager will notify you when the connection status changes.

If you're using Windows CE then Connection Manager isn't available and things are more difficult.  You can [bind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa926768.aspx) the socket to the specific adapter you want to use.  You can use the [IP Helper API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450040.aspx) to enumerate the adapters.

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment. It should run on both, CE and WM. So I think I have to use binding the socket to the local endpoint. I will try this and then tell you if it was successfull.

Answer (score 0):

Managing network switching between GSM/WLAN/... is not an easy task. Especially on Windows CE, where there is no Connection Manager API. Doing code in Compact Framework makes it eaven harder, as there are many P/Invokes and structures to rebuild.
On Windows CE you would need to poll WLAN and RAS connection status periodically to switch from one to the other. Then close and re.open connections, as the IP has changed.

Windows Mobile 6.x (except 6.5.x) will switch between WLAN and WWAN automatically if a connection is released and re-established.

There is a software NCP secure client avalable for Windows CE, Windows Mobile and others that seamlessly can switch transparent between network connections: https://www.ncp-e.com/en/products/centrally-managed-vpn-solution/managed-clients.html. Possibly this will help you. But it is a VPN environment, which then need to be used also for your WLAN.